# Transparent overlay view that only opens when application is first opened

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I believe I have the code for determining if my application has been opened before set in stone:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL didFirstLaunch = [defaults boolForKey:@"DidFirstLaunch"];
if (!didFirstLaunch) {
    [defaults setBool: YES forKey:@"DidFirstLaunch"];

    //Code for assembling overlay view
}
```

I put this code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

I want the transparent overlay view to only cover 3/4 of the iPhone screen and be slightly transparent so you can still see a little of the main page of my application -- it will have a couple pictures and text on it (basically a simple tutorial). **How do I go about creating a simple view of this nature?**

Comment: What is your question? You told us what you are doing and no more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
BOOL didFirstLaunch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"DidFirstLaunch"];

if (!didFirstLaunch) {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"DidFirstLaunch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, window.frame.size.width, window.frame.size.height)];
    //add some stuff to your transparent view. Example background color
    [v setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    // Finally set the alpha value
    [v setAlpha:0.3];
    [window addSubview:v];

}
```

Hope it helps. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the transparent overlay part of the question...

I think it's easiest to create a subview that overlays the entire screen, then subtract away the portion that you want. Here's some Swift code that may help:

```
// Create a view filling the screen.
let overlay = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 
    UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width,
    UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))

// Set a semi-transparent, black background.
overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.85)

// Create the initial layer from the view bounds.
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = overlay.bounds
maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

// Create the frame for the portion that you want to remove. 
// You could get this from a container view that holds all of 
// the subviews that you want to see behind the overlay.
let rect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100)

// Create the path.
let path = UIBezierPath(rect: overlay.bounds)
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

// Append the rectangle to the path so that it is subtracted.
path.appendPath(UIBezierPath(rect: rect))
maskLayer.path = path.CGPath

// Set the mask of the view.
overlay.layer.mask = maskLayer

// Add the view so it is visible.
self.view.addSubview(overlay)
```

Here is what the above code looks like in action:

[image]

I added a [library](https://github.com/TobogganApps/TAOverlayView) to CocoaPods that allows you to create semi-transparent overlays with rectangular/circular holes, allowing the user to interact with views behind the overlay. I used it to create this tutorial for one of our apps:

[image: Tutorial using the TAOverlayView]

The library is called [TAOverlayView](https://github.com/TobogganApps/TAOverlayView), and is open source under Apache 2.0.